# Braintree Excluding Library from Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, braintree

I have used following dependency in my Android Studio gradle.

```
    dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':wheel')
    compile project(':viewPagerLibrary')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.0.0'
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/analytics-3.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/androidasync-1.3.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
    compile files('libs/CWAC-Adapter.jar')
    compile files('libs/eventbus-2.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/fastjson-1.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    compile files('libs/ion-1.3.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/localytics.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids.jar')
    compile files('libs/parse-1.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/socialauth-4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.0.jar')
}
```

Now I need to implement Braintree Gradle dependency

```
compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.+'
```

But sometimes it show me some other error sometime its shows me java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 3.

I want to use this braintree dependency for payment options please help me out how can i use it without error with the current dependency.

Thanks a lot for solving my problem in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The Braintree Android library depends on GSON version 2.2.4 or higher.. It looks like you're currently depending on version `2.1.0`.  Upgrading your dependency to `2.2.+` should satisfy Braintree's and allow installation.

If you do run into further problems, Braintree's support can help, via email at support@braintreepayments.com or phone at 877.434.2894.